# Reuse Custom Security Test in Worklight

Tags: security, testing, ibm-mobilefirst

There are several Custom Security Tests have been created and deployed. It is no issue in one Worklight project to consume the customSecurityTest. But when other Worklight project also try to consume the same customSecurityTest. Got 401 Unauthorized error. The response on client side looks like /*-secure-
{"challenge.s":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"guhao08ggi00es5ec9r2mfshp3"}}}*/.

If the customSecurityTest could not be reused, it will defeat the whole purpose of reuse the security framework. Please help to solve it. Thanks!

Jerry

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate projects, you'll need to copy your securityTests. 
There is no sharing (at large) between projects.

If you have two applications of the same project, you could use the same securityTests in both.

I have to say that this limitation is not any defeat of the security framework's purpose...